# How to get Sum of Percentages by Employee and Line Nbr

Tags: sql

I have a data that set that gives me an employee and his/her percentage. An employee can have, say, five lines or four lines of percentage data. How do I aggregate based on the line number 1 thru 5 and then again from 1 to 4 etc.

My code is aggregating total for all line numbers 1 or 2 but not 1 thru 5.

| Employee | Line# | Pct |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | 10 |
| 1234 | 2 | 40 |
| 1234 | 3 | 50 |
| 1235 | 1 | 50 |
| 1235 | 2 | 30 |

I want the aggregate of 1234 to be 100 and 12345 to be 80.

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE, LINE_NBR,SUM(PLAN_PCT)
 FROM dbo.EmpPct
WHERE EMPLOYEE= 1234
GROUP BY LINE_NBR, EMPLOYEE
ORDER BY SUM(PLAN_PCT) DESC
```

Comment: your query is ok, just dont us LINE_NBR in it, not in select and not in group by

Comment: Can you please write down the result as you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want `1234` to be `100` and `1235` to be `80`, there is no use for `Line#`. Therefore, you have to exclude `Line#` from your `SELECT` statement. That's plain logic.

```
SELECT   EMPLOYEE, SUM(PLAN_PCT)
FROM     dbo.EmpPct
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE
ORDER BY SUM(PLAN_PCT) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE,SUM(PLAN_PCT)
 FROM dbo.EmpPct
WHERE EMPLOYEE= 1234
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE
ORDER BY SUM(PLAN_PCT) DESC
```